# JavaFX работа с SignalR

Tags: javafx

Пытаюсь написать клиент для чата на `JavaFX`. На сервере задействована библиотека `SignalR`. Подскажите пожалуйста пример реализации клиента (валится сразу на подключении):

```
HubConnection conn = new HubConnection("http://someserver.net");
HubProxy proxy = conn.createHubProxy("ChatHub");
conn.start();
```

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53003', transport: 'socket'
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53003', transport: 'socket'
>   ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]
>   )